# Paste rich text as plain text without HTML markup formatting in Trix editor

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, richtext, trix, actiontext

I am using Rich Text (Trix editor) with Rails and I want to be able to convert everything that user pastes to sanitized plain text instead of having formatted elements.
Based on Trix documentation I am using this code to convert pasted elements to string.

```
const element = document.querySelector("trix-editor")
  element.addEventListener("trix-paste", function(e) {
    element.editor.getDocument().toString()
    console.log(element.editor.getDocument().toString())
  })
```

In console, it shows correct plain text, but in the editor, all the elements are still formatted.

How can I replace text in the editor to this sanitized text?

Answer (score 1):

try this: https://github.com/basecamp/trix/issues/148

```
document.addEventListener('trix-before-paste', function (e) {
  if (e.paste.hasOwnProperty('html')){
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = e.paste.html;
    e.paste.html = div.textContent;
  }
});
```